# How to mathematically subtract two lists in python?

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I know subtraction of lists is not supported in python, however there are some ways to omit the common elements between two lists. But what I want to do is subtraction of each element in one list individually with the corresponding element in another list and return the result as an output list. How can I do this?

```
     A = [3, 4, 6, 7]
     B = [1, 3, 6, 3]
     print A - B  #Should print [2, 1, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.sub) with [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) module:

```
>>> A = [3, 4, 6, 7]
>>> B = [1, 3, 6, 3]
>>> map(operator.sub, A, B)
[2, 1, 0, 4]
```

As [@SethMMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399279/sethmmorton) mentioned below, in Python 3, you need this instead

```
>>> A = [3, 4, 6, 7]
>>> B = [1, 3, 6, 3]
>>> list(map(operator.sub, A, B))
[2, 1, 0, 4]
```

Because, [map](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#map) in Python returns an iterator instead.

Comment: Watch out, on python 3 this does not return a `list`, but a *map object*.  You need `list(map(operator.sub, A, B))` to get the same result.

Comment: @SethMMorton nice catch. I will add that to the answer

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> A = [3, 4, 6, 7]
>>> B = [1, 3, 6, 3]
>>> zip(A, B) # Just to demonstrate
[(3, 1), (4, 3), (6, 6), (7, 3)]
>>> [x - y for x, y in zip(A, B)]
[2, 1, 0, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```python
def substract_lists(a, b):
    for i, val in enumerate(a):
            val = val - b[i]
    return a
```